# Cannot get encryption class to work

Tags: php, security, encryption

I cannot get an encryption class to work (it's in a seperate file in the classes folder). The code for the class is:

```
class SymmetricCrypt
{
    // Encryption/decryption key.
    private static $msSecretKey = "Hello";

    // The initialisation vector.
    private static $msHexaIv = "c7098adc8d6128b5d4b4f7b2fe7f7f05";

    // Use the Rijndael Algorithm.
    private static $msCipherAlgorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;

    public static function Encrypt($plainString)
    {
        $binary_iv = pack("H*", SymmetricCrypt::$msHexaIv);

        // Encrypt source.
        $binary_encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(SymmetricCrypt::$msCipherAlgorithm, SymmetricCrypt::$msSecretKey, $plainString, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $binary_iv);

        // Convert $binary_encrypted_string to hexadeciaml format.
        $hexa_encrypted_string = bin2hex($binary_encrypted_string);
        return $hexa_encrypted_string;
    }

    public static function Decrypt($encryptedString)
    {
        $binary_iv = pack("H*", SymmetricCrypt::$msHexaIv);

        // Convert string in hexadecimal to byte array.
        $binary_encrypted_string = pack("H*", $encryptedString);

        // Decrypt $binary_encrypted_string,
        $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(SymmetricCrypt::$msCipherAlgorithm, SymmetricCrypt::$msSecretKey, $binary_encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $binary_iv);

        return $decrypted_string;
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling the class:

```
require_once 'classes/symmetric_crypt.php';
$sc = new SymmetricCrypt();
$password = "password";
$ec_password = $sc->Encrypt($password);

... insert into database.
```

If I echo the contents of $password, then it displays "password". If I echo $ec_password, it returns nothing.

I've used it before on a different project on a different server. Could it be something server-related? Any other ideas?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Shudders to think that people store my passwords as decryptable strings.  Use a one-way hash instead, please. Here is a good forum post on it: http://forums.devshed.com/security-and-cryptography-17/password-encryption-vs-hashing-398845.html

Comment: Thanks premiso.

I used md5 originally, although I stuggled with how to read the password. E.g. I could set the password, but tried and the code for a login form and that didn't work either!

Comment: @premiso: usually communication between platforms and organizations requires data to be decrypt-able. In that case using symmetric encryption becomes necessary.

Comment: @adrian You don't need to read the password. You need to get the password the user submitted via the form, hash it (adding the same salt) and compare it with the hashed value in the DB.

Comment: @adrianjohnson: you test for comparison, eg: if (md5($providedPassword) == $storedPassword) authorize();

Comment: Ahh. Thanks @Adrian. Almost got it working - adding it to a file I'm using as a header isn't working but I'm on my way to working it out. Adding it as a standalone PHP page works.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Works [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vBJFVu).

Two notes:

- Your initialization vectors should not be reused. Otherwise, it gets easier to find the encryption key (see WEP).
- Like premiso saids, you should not stored store passwords as decryptable strings. Use salted hashes with strong hash functions (not MD5!).